# Question regarding beginner Scrapy and scrapy crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I recently began to try to learn web scraping using Scrapy. Recently I tried to Scrapycrawl through the *books.toscrape.com*. According to the terminal, the Scrapycrawl call works fine, but it doesn't return the item count nor does it show any of the information on the books. I was wondering if this was normal, or if I have an error in my code.

Here is my code for the problem if this helps anyone understand what I was doing.

```
import scrapy

class BookspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bookspider"
    allowed_domains = ["books.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com"]


def parse(self, response):
    books = response.css('article.product_pod')
    for book in books:
    yield{
        'name': book.css('h3 a::text').get(),
        'url': book.css('h3 a').attrib['href'],
           }
        
    next_page = response.css('li.next a ::attr(href)').get()
    if next_page is not None:
        if 'catalogue/' in next_page:
             next_page_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/' + next_page
        else:
            next_page_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/' + next_page 
        yield response.follow(next_page_url , callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: well your indentation is wrong, but that might just be a copy and paste issue.  Otherwise your code seems fine and runs fine on my end.  It does produce the correct output including the count and extracted details.